# websocket, react and node js, does not send messages

Tags: reactjs, node.js, websocket, chat, express-ws

I'm trying to write a chat in React, and a node js express server side.
I found code in node js like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const expressWs = require('express-ws');
const port = 8000;
const app = express();
expressWs(app);

app.ws('/socket', (ws, req) => {
    // Handle WebSocket connections
    console.log('Client connected to WebSocket');
  
    // Listen for messages from clients
    ws.on('message', (message) => {
      // Handle incoming messages from clients
      console.log(`Received message: ${message}`);
  
      // Broadcast the message to all connected clients
      app.getWss().clients.forEach((client) => {
        if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          client.send(message);
        }
      });
    });
  });

app.listen(port);
```

And in the console I see:

> Client connected to WebSocket
> In React I wrote:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from 'websocket';

const Messagebox = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const socket = new W3CWebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/socket');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Listen for messages from the server
    socket.onmessage = (message) => {
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, message.data]);
    };

    // Clean up the socket connection on component unmount
    return () => {
      socket.close();
    };
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = (message) => {

    function isOpen(ws) { return ws.readyState === ws.OPEN }

    // Send a message to the server
    if (!isOpen(socket)) {
      console.log(message)
      //   return;
      socket.send(message);
    }
    else {
      console.log(" WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.");
    }

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {messages.map((msg, index) => (
          <div key={index}>{msg}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type your message..."
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            sendMessage(e.target.value);
            e.target.value = '';
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Messagebox;
```

And when I run I see that in the sendMessage function I get:

> WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
> How can the problem be solved?

I tried changing to this function:

```
const sendMessage = (message) => {
  // Check if the socket is open before sending a message
  if (socket.readyState === socket.OPEN) {
    console.log("Sending message:", message);
    socket.send(message);
  } else {
    console.log("WebSocket is not open. Message not sent.");
  }
};
```

But the websocket is still closed.